# Object Pointer Containing Vector out of Index

Tags: c++, pointers

Below is a simple markup of a program layout I can currently using. Its for OpenGL. Essentially I want to initialize the mesh before I ship it to the main loop. I can do this with

```
vector<Mesh> MeshContainer;
```

And once I initialize it, push it in the MeshContainer and then call it in the main loop like that. I would much rather be able to define a pointer in the Program struct, create the mesh in the init() function, and then store the pointer and then use the pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Mesh {

    vector<float> MeshVector;

};

struct Program {

    bool shouldClose = false;
    // Store the mesh as a pointer after we do some initialization.
    Mesh *mp;

    // Initialize is ran before the program and initializes before the loop begins.
    void init() {

        // Create the sudo-mesh.
        Mesh myMesh;

        // Give it some values. 9 in total.
        myMesh.MeshVector = {
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        };

        mp = &myMesh;

    }

    // This is ran in the loop.
    void run() {
        cout << mp->MeshVector[0] << endl;
    }

    void loop() {

        // Simulates layout of OpenGL application.
        init();

        // Program loop.
        while (!shouldClose) {
            // This simulates the draw loop.
            run();
        }
    }

};

int main() {

    // Create the program.
    Program app;
    app.loop();

    return 0;
}
```

However, even in this simple application I wrote up, it gives me "vector subscript is out of range". Now it is pretty pointless (pun intended) to do this because I'll eventually write up a memory management class to bypass all this hoopla, but while I learn, I'd like this to be my quick and dirty solution.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?
Should I be able to simply do:

```
cout << mp->MeshVector[0] << endl;
```

And get the result expected?

Edit:

My question does not involve a function returning a pointer. It simply looks to set a property of the struct to the pointer of some object I created in that method. Nothing is being returned.

Comment: The question I asked may resemble what may be a duplicate to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797769/returning-pointer-to-local-variable however one important note that my code does not return anything, I am simply defining an object in a function, and then pointing to it in a public pointer in a struct. No function written in my question and example does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
Mesh myMesh;
```

creates a local variable in `init()` and

```
mp = &myMesh;
```

creates a pointer to that local variable. However, this local variable does not exist anymore when you leave `init()`. Hence, accessing it results in undefined behavior.

The simple solution is to declare `myMesh` as a member variable of `Program` or to instantiate it on the heap with `Mesh* myMesh = new Mesh()` (and destroy it when you shut down).

Comment: I remember why I didn't do that in the first place, fixed that problem, and then avoided trying it afterwards. My mistake.

Comment: Go with the member variable if you can. The `new` approach adds a lot of complexity. But if you must, [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) are also worth checking out. They automate the memory management and protect you from the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Yes, a member variable will most certainly help me for now. Later down the road I won't be needing to do this as OpenGL VBO ID is the only reference I need post-initialization. Thanks.